# Creating item order within search panel in search view in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, group-by, odoo, status

[screen capture of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wXK.png)I'm trying to see if there is a way to change the order of items that are displayed in the search panel. I have specific need for the order I want my items to be displayed.

Currently search panel has items out of order and I can't find the logic it's built with.

I’m trying to reorder it so it shows in this order: distribution, awaiting approval, done. Currently it is displaying it in this order: awaiting approval, distribution, done: [search panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcnK7.png)

I tried to create groups and use Group By and use Order By, both in search view and tree view but that didn't work.

I also tried to update my python code and create compute state sequence, but that didn't work either

Comment: Where it's located that Search Panel? How to see what you are describing?

Comment: @aekis.dev 
Within searh view, you can create a search panel, that is displayed on the left of the screen.

Here is my xml for search view:

            <search>
                <field name="vendor_name" string="Vendor" filter_domain="['|', ('vendor_name', 'ilike', self), ('vendor_invoice_number', 'ilike', self)]"/>
                <searchpanel>
                    <field name="state" icon="fa-folder-open" enable_counters="1" select="multi"/>         
                </searchpanel>
            </search>

Comment: yes, but for what model?

Comment: I have already done what you want using the `crm.lead` as an example but your case could be different so I wanna give you an exact answer

Comment: It's a custom model for vendor invoices. It has a tree view with a search view and a search panel. It looks like crm.lead, my pipeline tab.

Comment: I cannot give you a solution without a way to check the scenario. The python model definition specifically for the state field

Comment: which odoo version ? could you provide a screen capture of your page

Comment: It's odoo 16 community edition. I updated the body of the question and added a screen capture there.

Comment: your state field is a selection or one2many?

Comment: @aekis.dev my state field in a selection field.

Answer (score 0):

For doing that with a selection field you have 2 options:

1. Order your Selection elements in the Python definition using alfanumeric order to make sure you will get that same order. For example:

```py
    won_status = fields.Selection([
        ('1_won', 'Won'),
        ('2_lost', 'Lost'),
        ('3_pending', 'Pending'),
    ], string='Is Won')
```

or

```py
    won_status = fields.Selection([
        ('aaa', 'Won'),
        ('bbb', 'Lost'),
        ('ccc', 'Pending'),
    ], string='Is Won')
```

2. Manually reorder your results according to the order that you wanna get. Like this:

```py
class CrmLead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    
    @api.model
    def search_panel_select_range(self, field_name, **kwargs):
        result = super(CrmLead, self).search_panel_select_range(field_name, **kwargs)
        # known result values
        # {'values': [{'id': 'pending', 'display_name': 'Pending', '__count': 9}, {'id': 'won', 'display_name': 'Won', '__count': 1}]}
        # that we need to transform into
        # {'values': [{'id': 'won', 'display_name': 'Won', '__count': 1}, {'id': 'pending', 'display_name': 'Pending', '__count': 9}]}
        # could be simpler like
        # result['values'] = result['values'].reverse()
        # or manually like following any pattern you want
        values_dict = {data['id']: data for in result['values']}
        result['values'] = [values_dict[elem] for elem in ['won', 'lost', 'pending']]
        return result
```